# Cucumber example iterate only once

Tags: webdriver, cucumber

I am using webdriver.io with cucumber. Following is my feature file:

```
    When I open specific tab
    And I select the option type as
    |option A   |
    |option B   |
    |option C|
    And I edit the that field and save
    Then I should be shown with successful message.
```

but when execute, it selects the given option one by one and then only for the last type it goes and edit the field and run the "Then" part.

I want to verify that edit the field is possible for each option type. What I am missing here? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to just write 3 scenarios. A bit of repetition in tests is not a big issue (unlike in code), especially if it gives you clear and simple scenarios.

Adding complexity to reduce the total number of scenarios is a bad trade off. The cost of the complexity far outweighs the cost of a bit more typing.